# (Java) Comparing values of two variables in if-statement but can't use `.equals()`

Tags: java, bluej

(Heads up, I've never written a proper program before so bear with me)

I'm trying to write an if-statement that compares the VALUES of the `position` fields of two instances (which literally returns the integer "position"). Problem is, they are private fields in different classes so I cannot access them directly. Instead, I made methods in each class which return the variable.

Now in my if-statement, this is the condition that is to be true/false:

`if (enemy1.getPosition() = player.getGun1Position())`

Now the problem is, if I use `=` the machine assumes I'm trying to assign a value to the position of `enemy1` and I've been researching to find that `==` compares the memory location rather than the value of the two fields.

I have also read that

`.equals()`

can be used but I'm assuming it can't be used here because

`enemy1.getPosition().equals(player.getGun1Position())`

gives an error when I try it.

**NOTE:** I cannot change the fields to public because this is for an assignment and the fields need to be private.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: What type is `position`?

Comment: Are you returning an `int` or an `Integer`?

Comment: If `getPosition()` returns an object of some kind (such as `Integer`), use `.equals`. If it returns a basic type (such as `int` or `double`), use `==`.

Comment: `equals()` gives you what error when you try it?

Comment: Also to further elaborate what khelwood said: If you want to compare two custom classes you need to `@Override` the `equals` method and fill it with your custom logic for comparison. If you don't do this it's the same as using `==` for the comparison.

Comment: I am returning an int (although I didn't know that there is a difference between `int` and `integer`). @khelwood But won't that compare the memory location rather than the value? I read that `==` will only return true if its the same variable...

Comment: @JaffarAli That applies to `Object`s. For basic types, like `int`, `==` is the correct way to compare them.

Comment: `==` does indeed compare the value for primitive data types such as `int`. It's called a shallow comparison if you want to read up on it.

Comment: Oh ok thank you, I will try that but it will be a while as I'm walking to class now

Comment: To say that `==` compares the memory location is only half of the truth. For object object references, that is more or less what happens.  For primitive types like `int`, it compares the values.  Think about it:  `int`s would be absolutely useless if you could only compare their memory addresses; every `int` variable would be unequal to every other `int` variable, and only equal to itself!

Comment: The compiler doesn't just give "an error", it provides a *very specific error* that will explain what's wrong. When asking for help, you need to post that specific message.

Comment: @chrylis Thank you, I will make sure to do so next time :D
@KevinAnderson That's exactly what I thought haha but I'm new to programming so I just thought it was one of those things that I would need to get used to, just like the fact that `=` is only used (in my context) for assigning values to other variables :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll briefly walk you through comparisons.

1) Primitives just need == operator to match values except, String values which are not permitives will compare their memory locations. for strings use .equals().

2) For objects of primitives like Integer,Double still compares the memory location with == operator. You need to invoke their .equals to compare them. If you have your own class you need to define your own version of equals method, means overriding.

Comment: `String`s are objects, too.  They're built into the language like `int`s and `float`s and whatnot, but they are not primitives.

Comment: @KevinAnderson, true, I edited the answer. It was not that clear. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `==` yet?

If it is truly retiring a integer, than `==` is the way to go.

You can not call functions on primitives like int, char, double, float, long,short,byte.  So there is no .equals() to call.

In the case of classes, you need to call .equals(), because a class variable is like a pointer, so you don't want to compare two pointers to each other with `==`.  However, primitive variables just contain their "values", so `==` is perfect for comparing values.

If you haven't tried this, you need to be more experimental with your coding.

Just test it.

```
System.out.println(enemy1.getPosition()+" == "+ player.getGun1Position()+":  "+(enemy1.getPosition()==player.getGun1Position()));

if(enemy1.getPosition()==player.getGun1Position())
{
//blah
}
```

If that doesn't work, then you are not returning an int primitive, but instead an Integer object (note the capital I).

In this case,

```
if(enemy1.getPosition().equals(player.getGun1Position()))
```

OR

```
if(enemy1.getPosition().getIntValue()==player.getGun1Position().getIntValue()))
```

Should work fine.

Comment: Thank you for clearing it up, no I didn't try `==` as I had read that it would only compare memory locations and thought that this was the case for all return types

Comment: No problem glad I could help.  I'm not trying to get down on your or anything, but being able to test things out will go a long way.